# Spring Webflux: How to create a Tomcat WAR for deployment?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-webflux

I've seen and tryed a lot of tutorial about spring-boot-starter-tomcat. But those worked for spring boot JPA but no for webflux.

Could you help me with that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot [does not support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) deploying a WebFlux application as a war file. If you want to use WebFlux, you should use jar packaging with an embedded container and launch your app using `java -jar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through below link to understand the choices
[webflux-server-choice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-server-choice)

Can you please try this see that works?

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux') { 
  exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', 
  module: 'spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty' 
} 
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
```

This is what I found in this link
[Learning Spring Boot 2.0 - Second Edition](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781786463784/2/ch02lvl1sec14/switching-from-embedded-netty-to-apache-tomcat)

Note: I am not sure about this is the right thing to do as I am not sure about the NIO capabilities of tomcat.

Comment: Not working. The war is compiled. But it doesn't work on Tomcat.